# Passing value from applet to PHP

Tags: java, php, url, applet

I want to send values of two variables to a PHP file from a Java applet), and I tried the following code.

```
try {
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(),"abc.php");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

con.setDoOutput(true);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());

ps.print("score="+score);
ps.print("username="+username);

con.getInputStream();

ps.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   g.drawString(""+e, 200,100);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException:protocol doesn't support output
```

Comment: @luk2302 You are totally wrong. This is how POST requests work.

Comment: Aehm, thats ... sadly ... true, too early in the morning -.- i`ll remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException:protocol doesn't support output
```

Means that you are using a protocol that doesn't support output.

`getCodeBase()` refers to a file url, so something like

```
file:/path/to/the/applet
```

The protocol is `file`, which doesn't support outout. You are looking for a `http` protocol, which supports output.

Maybe you wanted `getDocumentBase()`, which actually returns the web page where the applet is, i.e.

```
http://www.path.to/the/applet
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I used with my own applet, to send values (via POST) to a PHP script on my server:

I would use it like this:

```
String content = "";
   content = content + "a=update&gid=" + gid + "&map=" + getMapString();
   content = content + "&left_to_deploy=" + leftToDeploy + "&playerColor=" + playerColor;
   content = content + "&uid=" + uid + "&player_won=" + didWin;
   content = content + "&last_action=" + lastActionCode + "&appletID=" + appletID;

   String result = "";
   try {
    result = requestFromDB(content);
    System.out.println("Sending - " + content);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     status = e.toString();
   }
```

As you can see, I am adding up all my values to send into a "content" string, then calling my requestFromDB method (which posts my "request" values, and returns the server's response) :

```
  public String requestFromDB(String request) throws Exception
  {
    // This will accept a formatted request string, send it to the
    // PHP script, then collect the response and return it as a String.
    URL                 url;
    URLConnection   urlConn;
    DataOutputStream    printout;
    DataInputStream     input;
    // URL of CGI-Bin script.      
     url = new URL ("http://" + siteRoot + "/globalconquest/applet-update.php");

    // URL connection channel.
    urlConn = url.openConnection();
    // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
    urlConn.setDoInput (true);
    // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
    urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
    // No caching, we want the real thing.
    urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
    // Specify the content type.
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Send POST output.
    printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ());
    printout.writeBytes (request);
    printout.flush ();
    printout.close ();
    // Get response data.
    input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ());
    String str;
   String a = "";
    while (null != ((str = input.readLine())))
    {
      a = a + str;
    }

    input.close ();
    System.out.println("Got " + a);
    if (a.trim().equals("1")) {
       // Error!
       mode = "error";
    }

   return a;

  } // requestFromDB
```

In my PHP script, I would only need to look at $_POST for my values.  Then I would just print a response.

**Note!**  Your PHP script MUST be on the same server as the applet for security reasons, or this will not work.